# How does twilio verify charges occur?

Tags: twilio

On the documentation it says that its $0.05 charge per successful verification. Does this include the messaging cost? For example; if I send 100 otp verification to 100 **different** phone numbers **but none of them actually verify successfully**, then will my account be charged?

If I do get charged for text messages, what is the best practice to prevent a user from over-using my API to send otp's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Verify pricing page](https://www.twilio.com/verify/pricing) says:

> $0.05 per successful verification
>
> **plus standard fees per channel***
>
> *For SMS: $0.05 per successful verification + $0.0079 per SMS (US). See international SMS pricing [here](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us). See email pricing [here](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/).
> For WhatsApp: $0.05 per successful verification + $0.0147 (US) per
> business initiated conversation. See full WhatsApp pricing [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/pricing/).
> Push channel fee is included in the verification fee and is charged
> when a request is approved or denied. TOTP channel fee is included in
> the verification fee and is charged when a request is approved. Silent
> Network Auth channel is priced per country as a single, all-inclusive
> fee; [talk to an expert](https://interactive.twilio.com/silent-network-auth-sales-1?_ga=2.38347939.1487237767.1670239906-25302259.1670239906) for details.

Therefore, yes, you will get charged for the messages even if no one verifies successfully. In the end, you can do nothing if your users enter wrong phone numbers without verifying. The messages get delivered, and therefore you need to pay for them. I would argue the other way around and say that Verify still saves you money as it prevents  [SMS Traffic Pumping Fraud](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/8360406023067-SMS-Traffic-Pumping-Fraud).